# Nested Struct in a struct ksqldb

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I am performing a create stream Select As statement which is joining a stream and table.

The stream has a nested struct, and would like to take all the attributes defined in the stream to be joined with the table and created a nested structure as follows
a{b{c}}

b{c} is how the nested struct for the stream A,

B is the table.

How would i accomplish this

Following doesn't work.

````
SELECT 
 A.*,
 STRUCT(B.*) as B
FROM STREAM_A A 
INNER JOIN TABLE_B ON A.key = B.key;```
````

Comment: Not sure if I can follow? You just want to wrap `STRUCT B(...)` with another outer layer? Ie, instead of b->c you get a->(b->c) ? You can nest struct but you need to declare is expliclity: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/select-pull-query/#struct-output